# sql server parsing char to int

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL server databases which use the same code.

I am getting below error:

```
 Error when executing tsp_parse_str_int at line 26. Error message: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1000 ' to data type int.
```

If you notice there is a leading space, however in my code I am removing the space before the conversion!

```
    SET @temp = (select replace(@temp, ' ', ''))
    SET @projid = cast(@temp as int)
```

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it was actually not a space, either a carriage return tab or new line, I got rid of by:

REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyField, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SET @temp = (select RTRIM(@temp))
SET @projid = cast(@temp as int)
```

`RTRIM` trims the right space and `LTRIM` would trim the left space. To remove spaces from both the left and right at the same time `LTRIM(RTRIM(@temp))`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code below in SQL Server 2012 and it works *without* any trimming at all. Are you sure it is just a normal ' ' and not another hidden character?

```
declare @temp nvarchar(20)
declare @projid int
set @temp = '  12345    '
--SET @temp = (select replace(@temp, ' ', ''))
SET @projid = cast(@temp as int)
select @projid
```